# firefox 57 inspect object in console is gone

Tags: javascript, firefox, console, firefox-developer-tools

for love of god, please someone tel me how can I bring back `object inspect` in firefox 57 like following image

[image]
this is what firefox 57 doing on objects in console:

[image]

in firefox 57, the whole developer tool has been re-designed, and it's freaking me out, because every objects and requests in console opens inline and it's ridicules.

Comment: Why is it ridiculous? When you are clicking from one object to another to compare in right panel?

Comment: yeah but when was the last time you've done this kind of compare ? @NoBugs

Comment: I don't remember when. Is that the only reason you want it to open to the right of the console?

Comment: @NoBugs Not, this is not. It's good to have log and variable inspect separately not in same panel and you should know, there gonna be a lot of vertical scrolling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is [Bug 1405900 - Web console behavior has changed for the worse](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1405900)

Tracked on [Bug 1380501 - [meta] Add ability to open an expanded ObjectInspector in a sidebar](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1380501)